# Converting the value in primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces data table. In one of the columns the value that I am displaying needs to be converted to different name. Can you please tell me how to do it? Below is the column:

```
 <h:outputText value="#{ticket.ticketType}" rendered="#{column eq 'ticketType'}"/>
```

Here the ticketType value needs to be different from what actually getting displayed. 
I cannot change the ticket object implementation.

Comment: Can you post what is that other form you want to display?

Comment: What do you exactly want to display from ticket?